# How to create forex currency pairs correlation matrix by tableau

Tags: matrix, tableau-api, currency, correlation, forex

My data format is like this:

```
date    symbol  normalized.rate
1   9/14/2018   AUD/CAD 0.370231687
2   9/15/2018   AUD/CAD 0.335662465
3   9/16/2018   AUD/CAD 0.336063656
4   9/17/2018   AUD/CAD 0.366654408
5   9/18/2018   AUD/CAD 0.416452141
6   9/19/2018   AUD/CAD 0.444167698
7   9/20/2018   AUD/CAD 0.447210057
8   9/21/2018   AUD/CAD 0.475259938
9   9/22/2018   AUD/CAD 0.486961319
10  9/23/2018   AUD/CAD 0.482782254
11  9/24/2018   AUD/CAD 0.458510247
12  9/25/2018   AUD/CAD 0.44460232
13  9/26/2018   AUD/CAD 0.49481796
14  9/27/2018   AUD/CAD 0.51036408
15  9/28/2018   AUD/CAD 0.411136371
16  9/29/2018   AUD/CAD 0.32934372
17  9/30/2018   AUD/CAD 0.321771255
18  10/1/2018   AUD/CAD 0.216341814
19  10/2/2018   AUD/CAD 0.168081977
20  10/3/2018   AUD/CAD 0.085771121
```

Following there are other currency pairs like EUR/USD etc. I want to create a correlation matrix by tableau. I searched for some resource and tried to join itself by the date and it looks like this:

```
F1  Date        Symbol  Normalized.Rate F1 (pairs back.csv1)    Date (Pairs Back.Csv1)  Symbol (Pairs Back.Csv1)    Normalized.Rate (Pairs Back.Csv1)
1   9/14/2018   AUD/CAD 0.370232    6,879   9/14/2018   ZAR/JPY 0.10887
1   9/14/2018   AUD/CAD 0.370232    6,698   9/14/2018   USD/ZAR 0.94164
1   9/14/2018   AUD/CAD 0.370232    6,517   9/14/2018   USD/TRY 0.80341
1   9/14/2018   AUD/CAD 0.370232    6,336   9/14/2018   USD/SEK 0.33269
1   9/14/2018   AUD/CAD 0.370232    6,155   9/14/2018   USD/NOK 0.17961
1   9/14/2018   AUD/CAD 0.370232    5,974   9/14/2018   USD/MXN 0.11480
1   9/14/2018   AUD/CAD 0.370232    5,793   9/14/2018   USD/JPY 0.67025
1   9/14/2018   AUD/CAD 0.370232    5,612   9/14/2018   USD/CNH 0.60293
```

And next I have no idea how to make the correlation matrix. 
What the code for caculated field should be?

It is easy to create the matrix in R, but I have no idea to make it in tableau.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/creating-a-correlation-value-matrix

Comment: @DanielSims Yes, that's what I am checking. But still can not work it out.

Comment: What issues are you encountering while going through the knowledge base article?

Comment: @Andy The step2, I don't know how to write the script.